# Getting a rented movie from iPod touch back to the PC

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, data-synchronization, movie

I just rented a movie using iTunes on Windows 7 and then transferred the movie to my 4th gen iPod touch using drag & drop.

It has disapeared from the list on the PC, and I have not started watching the movie yet.

Now I want watch it on the PC, how do I get it back on the PC?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to rent the movie again if you did not watch it within 30 days of renting.

1. The movie will disappear from your iTunes library
2. You will not be able to transfer the movie from your iDevice to iTunes

More information here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1657

Answer (score 0):

You have to send it back using the Rental box on the Movies tab in the iPod settings in iTunes.

Comment: There is no such thing in iTunes 11. Can you describe where I find the menu for this?

Comment: @bitbonk, maybe you should edit your question because you never mentioned you were on iTunes 11 (which didn't exist publicly when you asked the question).